# Change look/shape of selectInput and numericInput boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to change the look of some of my Shiny UI elements to make them more in line with the aesthetics of the rest of a website.

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to remove the rounded edges of the `selectInput` boxes to make it look something like this:

[image: Example of squared selectInput]

Secondly, I was hoping to make a `numericInput` box that looks similar to the following:

[image: Example of plus minus numericInput]

Is there an easy way to do this?  I'm pretty comfortable in R, but don't know a huge amount of css or html.  I'd thought about flanking a `numericInput` with `actionButton` elements to use as plus/minus keys, but haven't figured out how to make them look like the above.

Are there any style attributes or javascript libraries I can incorporate to achieve either of these two things?

Comment: Can't really do anything without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Rounded edges is almost certainly css `border-radius`, either setting that to 0 on the style or adding a css class with `border-radius: 0` should fix that problem

Comment: These are actually two questions. The first one already has an answer. Please, ask the two questions in separate posts.

Answer (score 2):

As ash commented, for the first question, you can remove the rounding by setting the `border-radius` to `0px`:

```
shinyApp(
  ui=fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(".selectize-input {border-radius:0px}"),
      tags$style(".selectize-input.dropdown-active {border-radius:0px}"),
      tags$style(".selectize-dropdown {border-radius:0px}")),
    selectInput("select", "Select", 1:3)),
  server=function(input, output){})
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks so much@ash and @HubertL.  This works great: I'd already adjusted my font size using selectize-input, but didn't realize there was a border-radius option too. I've figured there was probably an easy way to do this, while the second part of my question was probably more tricky/not doable.

Comment: @HubertL do you know how to address the pickerInput from the shinyWidgets library in this manner?